# How to store results of an Update statement in a CTE (using output) and Insert a record for each updated item

Tags: sql-server, output, common-table-expression

I need to update several rows and for all updated rows insert a log in another table.

The output of a UPDATE statement doesn't seem to be considered a valid "query" for a CTE. What am I doing wrong?

```
WITH cte AS (UPDATE processowner SET Owner=1 OUTPUT inserted.[ProcessId] WHERE Owner=2)
INSERT INTO processlog ([ProcessId],[Event],[Note]) VALUES (cte.[ProcessId],'something happened','the note')
```

Answer (score 0):

here, I am using table variables, but that should give you an idea, you could also do triggers on the table to log changes.

```
declare @processowner table(processid int, Owner int);
insert into @processowner values(1,1);
insert into @processowner values(1,2);
insert into @processowner values(1,3);

declare @updated table(processid int);


UPDATE @processowner SET [Owner]=1 
    OUTPUT inserted.[ProcessId] 
    into @updated
WHERE [Owner]=2;

select * From @processowner;
```